# Angular 9 - Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency

Tags: angular, circular-dependency

I have angular application with (among other things) two services. ApiService and AuthServiceService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class APIService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

and

```
 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthServiceService {
  currentUser: User;

  token: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private jwt: JwtHelperService, private api: APIService ) {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');

    this.setCurrentUser(this.token);


    this.api.getMyProfile().subscribe(u => {
// some code    

    });

   }
```

When I open web page I get error **Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! AuthServiceService** and I can't find where did I make that circular dependency.

I've isolated problem to **private api: APIService** in AuthServiceService constructor. If I remove that parameter, error is gone.

I've installed madge, but it also can't find any problem with circular dependencies

> PS D:\Web\ClientApp> npx madge --circular --extensions ts ./
>
> Processed 127 files (20.1s) (45 warnings)
>
> √ No circular dependency found!

What to do next? How to find what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This error basically means that your app is going in circles. Since removing the API service in the auth component fixes something, can you tell me if the APIService is pointing back to the AuthService? My guess is it is, thus the app keeps going in circles (where the word cyclic comes in)

Comment: Since it doesn't look like this should create a cyclic dependency, I guess I'd try "providing" these in the module old-style, instead of using `providedIn: 'root'`, just to see if it's any different. It might fix it, or at least give you a better error message....

Comment: Still no solution. I've removed ApiService reference from AuthService and implement that single call I needed directly in AuthService but still have same error when I call this.http.get<string>(apiAddress, { responseType: 'text' as any }).subscribe( ......

Comment: Got it!!! I have HttpInterceptor with AuthService injected in constructor. Since I call http.get in constructor of AuthService, interceptor tries to create new AuthService and there is cyclic dependency. I've added setTimeout in constructor of AuthService that trigger http.get after 20ms and it works.